# Upgrade .net core 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1

I am upgrading .NET core 2.1 to 3.1 in my WEB API. I have already implemented the JWTBearer logic in my .NET API long time ago.

But when I upgraded my API from 2.1 to 3.1 the issue is JWT bearer name space not found error.

I have upgraded the Microsoft.AspNetCore.APP from 2.1 to 2.2 (Latest) which is the root assembly for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer. Though the reference available in the packages it's not available in the name space.

So getting build errors.

Comment: Did you install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` nuget package?

Comment: did you configure the project to use version 3.1?

Comment: Yes, If we install Microsoft.AspNetCore.APP that would install JWTBearer Yes,Configured my API project to 3.1

Comment: Refer to the migration steps from [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references). There are plenty of migration steps to follow. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies):

[image]

We can see that the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll` has already removed from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package from Asp.net Core 3.0 version. And when migration application from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0, it already suggests removing the obsolete package references.

[image]

So, in the asp.net core 3.1 application, to implement JWT authentication, we need to install the following packages:

- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

More detail information, see [Implement JWT In ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-jwt-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)
.

Comment: Thanks for the Info Zhi Lv !

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been resolved. I have installed JWT 3.1.9 version .

The exact assembly is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.

This supports .Net core 3.1 framework.

Thanks !

Comment: Your answer doesn't add any more info than Zhi's, other than a specific version number. Rather than making a redundant answer, you should just accept Zhi's answer, and delete yours.

Comment: The issue is with version number only. So I have gone through the versions available for JWT. It works .

Comment: Zhi specifically said to add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer. Your answer only adds a specific version number on top of that. That's a minor detail you could leave in a comment.

Comment: Actually I have tried to add the assembly before Zhi's comment .Until you find a correct assembly's version  that doesn't work . Hope you got it.